# AccesDenied request is not forwarded to AuthenticationEntryPoint if multiple AuthenticationProvider exist

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

In a Spring Security project I have configured Keycloak via the regular `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` method. Everything works fine with Keycloak itself.

I now have added one specific URL that needs to be authorized via basic-auth. For that, I have configured a second configuration, with an `antMatcher` to that URL that has higher priority than the Keycloak-configuration. This works fine, when I access that URL, basic auth is triggered and I can authenticate for it.

But after authenticating for this URL, I can no longer authenticate via my Keycloak-specific URL. The current logic is as follows: I have a Keycloak-login URL (`/auth/login`), which is handled by a controller in my project. The handling method is annotated with `@Secured`, requiring the user to have a role that he only gets after authenticating with Keycloak. So for the first login, the request to the `/auth/login` URL is denied, an `AccessDeniedException` is thrown. 
What Spring then automatically does in `ExceptionTranslationFilter`: It delegates the request to the authentication entrypoint, which is a Keycloak specific implementation which does all the magic.

The problem in this specific case is, however, that in [`ExceptionTranslationFilter#handleSpringSecurityException`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java) Spring will not delegate to the authentication entry point, if the user is not "anonymous". Because the user has previously authenticated for a basic-auth URL, Spring finds this authentication object in the context and then does not consider the user as anonymous. I guess the logic here is that Spring considered this a failed login-attempt or something.

What can I do so that Spring also delegates the request to the configured authentication entry point if it finds some unrelated authentication in the context?

Comment: *I guess the logic here is that spring considered this a failed login-attempt or something.* Your guess is wrong. An already logged in user is not redirected to the authentication entry point, because it is not neccessary to login (it is already done). The user should get an 403 error.

Comment: However, you could add an access denied handler and redirect your user to your entry point.

Comment: @dur Thanks for your comment. I have thought about that, but it seems ... dirty? Seems kind of hacky. I will give it a try and see how the results look like, although I don't know how I will get access to the appropriate authentication entrypoint inside of the accesDenied handler, but there probably is a way.

Comment: Somehow making the AccessDeniedHandler call the correct AuthenticationEntryPoint's commence seems very hacky indeed to be honest. I don't think that this should be the way of doing this. Then again, I don't think this whole scenario is something one should be doing in the first place, as there is no clean solution to it and its probably just not meant to work. I'll most likely just pass on having basic-auth as well